# EditText height change troubles

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have `EditText` which dynamically change height. So I have problem with editing text.. Text is hidden, please see screenshot:
[image]

Code:

```
final EditText editText = new EditText(getContext());
editText.setHint("?");

editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxAnswerLength.length())});
float measureText = editText.getPaint().measureText(maxAnswerLength);
editText.setWidth(editText.getPaddingLeft() + editText.getPaddingRight() + (int) measureText);
editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
editText.setTextSize(TEXT_SIZE);
editText.setSingleLine(true);

addView(editText);

editText.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    private int measuredHeight;

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (measuredHeight == 0) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = editText.getLayoutParams();
            measuredHeight = editText.getMeasuredHeight();
            layoutParams.height = measuredHeight / 2;
            editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }
});
```

So, what I doing wrong ?

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/matcher_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.***.ui.customviews.EditableTextView
        android:id="@+id/editable_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint in the `measuredHeight = editText.getMeasuredHeight();` in order to check the actual height? Also Why don't you try with `editText.getHeight()` instead?

Comment: also, please post layout file here

Comment: @astinx Yeah, size is not 0. editText.getHeight() don't use because it's return 0.

Comment: @NikMyers xml added into body of question.

Comment: Why not just change the text size?

Comment: @TaylorCourtney it's don't resolve problem. Text smaller but centering in above path of EditText

Comment: Sorry, please clarify

Comment: @TaylorCourtney just see image. http://www.screencast.com/t/ISR2X8w5

Comment: `layoutParams.height = measuredHeight / 2;` looks like your taking your original height and halving it...Remove this line

Comment: Sorry about that the original image in the post was blocked

Comment: Try wrapping context of layout?

Comment: @inner_class7 But I want change size of editText, how I can do it right ?

Comment: @TaylorCourtney what you mean, please tell more..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I found solution for this problem:

```
editText.setPadding(-5, -5, -5, -3);
```

Thanks.